# Will two URLs have duplicate etags have their representations treated as swappable?

Tags: http-headers

Will two URLs that both give the same etag have their representations treated as swappable?

For example if I have two images A.gif and B.gif and for some reason GET /A.gif and GET /B.gif both result in the same etag header, will A.gif occasionally be replaced by B.gif in the client's browser and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [Steve Clay addresses this very question.](http://mrclay.org/index.php/2009/03/03/you-probably-dont-need-etag/)

Answer (score 3):

No.  A given URL has its own ETag entry in the browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think so, etag tells the browser whether to fetch the image from server, or to use the cached version of THAT image. it does not act like some sort of a hash.